# Como comparar duas string marcando as diferenças?

Tags: c#, winforms

Digamos que eu tenha as `strings`:

`Oi, meu nome é ítalo` e `Olá, meu nome é ítalo`

Como gerar um resultado +- assim:

**Oi**, meu nome é ítalo

**Olá**, meu nome é ítalo

O sistema deve marcar de alguma forma a parte da `string` que está diferente.

Antes que alguém pergunte o que já fiz, quero dizer que não tenho nem ideia de como fazer, por isso postei a pergunta.

Comment: tenta pegar dois richtextbox e ir percorrer o texto comparando-os... enquanto estiver diferente... altera a cor do texto....enquanto estiver igual, mantém... ps. Pra evitar os votos negativos, tenta ser mais claro, especificar onde quer fazer isso (winforms,wpf,web,etc) essas coisas...

Comment: Uma possibilidade que eu vejo é fazer `split` por espaços e comparar palavras entre frases e assinalar as que não estão nos dois arrays resultantes dos `split`s

Comment: veja se é tipo isso que queres fazer: https://www.diffchecker.com/diff

Comment: Exatamente isso @RovannLinhalis alguma sugestão de código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu só comecei a fazer o código aqui, mas não posso parar pra fazer isso por agora, segue o código inicial:

```
    private void Comparar(RichTextBox rtb1, RichTextBox rtb2)
    {
        rtb1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        rtb1.BackColor = Color.Empty;

        string[] texto1 = rtb1.Text.Split(' ');
        string[] texto2 = rtb2.Text.Split(' ');
        int removidas = 0;
        for (int i =0 ; i < texto1.Length;i++)
        {
            if (texto2.Length > i - removidas)
            if (texto1[i] != texto2[i-removidas])
            {
                rtb1.Select(rtb1.Text.IndexOf(texto1[i], i), texto1[i].Length);
                rtb1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Orange;
                removidas++;
            }
        }

    }
```

Obviamente ainda é só um protótipo, mas já dá pra começar. O resultado foi o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar uma biblioteca que gere comparação textual.

A biblioteca [google-diff-match-patch](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-diff-match-patch/) está disponível em várias linguagens.

Para utilizar a versão em C#, basta fazer o download da última versão do arquivo `diff_match_patch.zip` e adicionar o arquivo `DiffMatchPatch.cs` ao seu projeto.

A comparação poderá ser feita da seguinte forma:

```
string text1 = "Oi, tudo bem?";
string text2 = "Olá, tudo bem?";

var dmp = new diff_match_patch();
var diffs = dmp.diff_main(text1, text2);
var html = dmp.diff_prettyHtml(diffs);
```